# do report viewer work in 64bit processor?

Tags: c#

I have already program and setup runs on XP 32 built processor.. works Fine. Now in want same setup to be run on windows 7 64 bit.Problem on 64 bit when i build the setup is  'type or name space 'reporting' could not be found.. How to achieve this(Microsoft.Reporting.W informs)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your project's Platform Target to "x86" instead of "Any CPU"